# Bootstrap - Add a frame after clicking a card

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

im new to the whole Angular/Web Development world. I am currently trying to improve my HTML/CSS skills and ran into a problem I couldnt solve myself.
I am using Bootstrap in my angular project and implemented the cards component.
[the card for my usecase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOj9R.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOj9R.png)
I added hover effects with css and made the whole card clickable, now I want to implement a frame/border after the card get clicked (as shown in the image).
Does anyone knows a way to do this ?

Best Regards
tschanni

.....................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question doesn’t contain any example of your code but you could do something like adding an `onclick` or add an event listener to toggle a “clicked” class with the desired border: i.e.

```
<div class="card" onclick="this.classList.toggle('clicked')">card</div>
```

With CSS

```
.card {width: 50px; height: 100px;}
.clicked {border: 1px solid red;}
```

[an example](https://codepen.io/sean-conkie/pen/yLqaJyQ)

Comment: That worked out pretty well. Next time I will post an code example - trying to improve. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple and code-readable way, for example add this CSS:

```
.card.selected {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

And JavaScript click event:

```
const card = document.querySelector('.card');

card.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('selected');
});
```